# Linking two DIV tags using javascript

Tags: jquery

Here is my smaller image link:

```
$("#thumbnail").append('<img src="' + response + '" height="200" width="200"/>');
```

And I need to link with the bigger image link:

```
$("#Original").append('http://localhost:XXXX' + fileObj.filePath);
```

If I click the smaller link the bigger Image should open

So how do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [jQuery click() method](http://api.jquery.com/click/) allows to bind a function to the mouse click event. To open your big image on a new window whenever your thumbnail (a `div` perhaps?) is clicked, you may use the following:

```
$("#thumbnail").click(function() { window.open('YOUR_URL'); }
```

Comment: You are welcome, Volety. Please remember to mark my answer as accepted, if that is the case. :)

Comment: Hi, I have another simple query can you do just help me in this?It's nothing but I am giving an hyperlink as <a href="javascript: $("#Image").click(function () {
//                    window.open('http://localhost:50562' + fileObj.filePath)" rel="lightbox" title="my caption">Click Me</a> and in the uploadify script I have mentioned as  $("#thumbnail").append('<img src="' + response + '" height="200" width="200" />') but the enlarged image is not showing up.